# Multiclass (OVR) Logistical Regression on "Surrounded" Classes

Tags: classification, multiple-regression, sigmoid-curve

I'm trying to understand/visualize how multiclass logistic regression works but most of the examples I've seen concern 3 classes with all of them on the outside.

How does logistic regression work when there is a class surrounded by all the others. I imagine there would have to be a dip or trough in the logistic curve in order to set a bounds on the values needed - how do you differentiate between the two classes that are in the upper threshold for example?

Are there simply some cases where you couldn't use a logistic regression model - as in cases where there's only a sweet spot between two extremes where a data point lies in a class? How would you achieve this with a logistic curve?

Edit: To help visualize what I'm taking about. The picture below has three classes but they are all outside, so there's a clear, single boundary in at least one dimension separating them
[image]

However in this screenshot, there is a green class surrounded by all the others. So given any dimension, it's going to be between two other classes. Assuming using OVR, how would you decide a point is in that class but not the others without having a regression curve that has a peak or trough in it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean something like a multicolored bullseye with a circle (or whatever) of points from certain classes surrounding most or all of the points in another class?

Comment: Hi Dave, yes, that's exactly what I mean. A class with values in between two or more outer classes - less than one and greater than another.